# Datarow array in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net

I would like create Crystal Report in vb.net with data from database. How can I put data from datarow array in report? I don't want to use dataset in my report.

Comment: If you don't want to use dataset, you can use datatable instead.

Comment: How Can I put data from datatable in form to report?